# Using grep to list lines starting with

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

I am trying to Use the GREP command to list all lines which contain the letter
'd' at least twice in a row (that is, next to each other), from file "test". But i can't get it to work. Can someone please help?

I can't display what I want. And am not sure how this works. I tried `grep [dd]` but that didn't work.

This is extremely confusing for me

Comment: so you are saying basic functionality of `grep` is not working? `grep dd test` what did this gave you?

Comment: Title says : "Using grep to list lines with"; but the question does not make any reference to that requirement.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Note that a character class matches a *single* character. Hence the list of characters in a character class is really a *set*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should make it:

```
grep dd <your_file>
```

Comment: how would I be able to make it search for more than 2 d's in a row?

Comment: This will list the lines where "dd" has been found. Therefore, if a line contains, say, "ddddd", then it will be listed as well since it obviously contains "dd"...

Comment: And you don't need the ".txt". It was just to show that this is a file.

Answer (score 7):

In regex:

^ character means, start of data line.
all characters match themselves.

So, if you are trying to find lines starting with 'dd', try:

```
grep ^dd <your_file>
```

However if you just interested in finding out lines with 'dd' pattern, try:

```
grep dd <your_file>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `grep [dd]` was specifying any line with a character from the set (set = []) containing "d" and "d".  So simply putting them side-by-side without the square brackets provides the method for all lines containing a "d" with another "d" right after it.

```
cat yourfile | grep dd
grep dd yourfile
grep dd <yourfile
```

should all work, assuming you replace "yourfile" with your file's name.

If you really were looking for lines starting with two or more "d"s, using Sagar's "^dd" instead of just "dd".  Similarly, you could use "dd$" for lines *ending* with two or more "d"s.

You might try "man regexp" or http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm for some more info.